# SharePoint user login status

Tags: office-365

It is possible to get the all Sharepoint users current status i.e : Available or busy or away like using Jquery, Javascript, C#, Rest API else Json?

Comment: Show what you have tried while asking a question. Check this link [ask]

Comment: My concern is to show the user connect status such as whether user is now available or away by showing flag. Ex: If user online then set flag 1 else set flag 2 in the webpart page on page load